# What's the difference between memcpy, memmove, and strncpy for copying data in C programming?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char src[19] = "abcdef";

    char *target = src;

    memcpy(target+3,target,5);
    printf("from memcpy  : %s\n", target);

    strncpy(target+3,target,5);
    printf("from strncpy : %s\n", target);

    memmove(target+3,target,5);
    printf("from memmove : %s\n", target);
}
```

```
from memcpy  : abcabcde
from strncpy : abcabcab
from memmove : abcabcab
```

i see different function names but the usage is the same i have searching on google microsoft some of the developers say that is it deprecated and harmeful i want to understand which one of these functions is the right for copying data  in c language ?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Like the `man` pages?

Comment: yes i read the documentation

Comment: And? It is in the first lines of the description: *"The strcpy() function copies the string pointed to by src,
       including the terminating null byte ('\0'), to the buffer pointed
       to by dest."* vs *"The memcpy() function copies n bytes from memory area src to
       memory area dest.  The memory areas must not overlap.  Use
       memmove(3) if the memory areas do overlap."*

Comment: that is the problem i don't understand what they mean by overlaping

Comment: Overlapping means partially (or fully) occupying the same region of memory. Like if you want to copy first 10 elements of an array to the same array staring at index `2`, for instance. You should have asked *that* question instead.

Comment: what i understand from you is : "abced" if i say : memcpy(target+3,target,5) the string should be written as "abcabcab" not "abcabcde" because this is overlaping am i right ?

Comment: Since you are using `memcpy` and the buffers do overlap, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: so that is the meaning of overlap

Comment: i now understand it

Comment: Think of how you would implement `memcpy`. You will probably make a loop that will copy the data elementwise.  What will happen if source and destination overlap? In your case you are first overwriting `target[3]` with `target[0]`, so when you get to copy `target[3]` it does not have the original value anymore. Since the Standard does not require any specific implementation of `memcpy`, this behavior does not have to be the same as with your naive implementation, so it is simply undefined.

Comment: Side note:  pretty much the only reason for even having separate `memcpy()` and `memmove()` implementations (instead of just using `memmove()` everywhere) is that in some cases `memcpy()` can be made slightly more efficient because it is allowed to assume that the target-range and the source-range do not overlap.  (`memmove()` implementations, OTOH, are required to check for that possibility and handle it correctly, which requires some extra CPU cycles)

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

1. `memmove` copies `n` bytes from `src` to `dest`.
2. `memcpy` copies `n` bytes from `src` to `dest`, as long as the two regions do not overlap.
3. `strncpy` copies `n` bytes, or up to a `\0` byte, from `src` to `dest`, whichever comes first.  (And as long as the two regions do not overlap.)  Also it pads the destination out to `n` characters using `\0`, if necessary.

If you don't want to think about all this, just always use `memmove`.  In particular (and as you can see by the length of my "simple" description of it with respect to the others), `strncpy` is too weird and complicated to be generally useful.

[Footnote: you didn't ask about `strlcpy`, but it's quite useful, and does what you probably wanted `strncpy` to do.]

To demonstrate the difference between `strncpy` and `memcpy`:

```
char a[] = "hello";
char b[] = "world";

strncpy(a, "pq\0rs", 5);

printf("after strncpy: a = %c %c %c %c %c = %s\n",
            a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a);

memcpy(b, "pq\0rs", 5);

printf("after memcpy: b = %c %c %c %c %c = %s\n",
            b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b);
```

This prints

```
after strncpy: a = p q      = pq
after memcpy:  b = p q  r s = pq
```

Notice that `memcpy` copied everything, while `strncpy` only copied the first two characters `p` and `q`, and then zeroed out the rest.

Most of the time, the source and destination regions do not overlap.  Here's an example where they do:

```
char x[] = "abcdefghi";
memmove(&x[3], &x[0], 6);
printf("after memmove: %s\n", x);

char y[] = "abcdefghi";
memcpy(&y[3], &y[0], 6);
printf("after memcpy:  %s\n", y);
```

On my machine this prints:

```
after memmove: abcabcdef
after memcpy:  abcabcdbc
```

This code fragment tries to copy the first 6 characters of the string on top of the last 6 copies of the string.  Using `memmove`, this works, resulting in `abcabcdef`.  But using `memcpy`, we get a wrong result, because by the time it tries to copy the `def`, they have already been overwritten by `abc`.  (Actually it's a bit more complicated than that, but hopefully you get the idea.)

Comment: that is the problem i am not understanding ``overlaping`` you mean when the same object doesn't get written the number of times we want ?

Comment: @Bishop Think of it as overlapping intervals. They have common parts i.e. their intersection is non-empty.

Comment: @Bishop: `memcpy(target+3,target,5)` copies bytes from `target[0]`, `target[1]`, `target[2]`, `target[3]`, and `target[4]` to `target[3]`, `target[4]`, `target[5]`, `target[6]`, and `target[7]`. The bytes `target[3]` and `target[4]` are in both the source and the destination, so the source and the destination overlap. The C standard does not specify what `memcpy` does when there is an overlap.

Answer (score 0):

memcpy and memmove operate dependently AND independently of data type. From the Linux man pages:

> The memcpy() function copies n bytes from memory area src to memory area dest.  The memory areas must not overlap. Use memmove(3) if the memory areas do overlap.

To address my apparent contradiction: if I have int[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37Zoi.png), that is 8 bytes (assuming we're not on an old 16-bit system where int is 2 bytes). Note what happens when I try to copy 1 int:

```
char hex(char num) {
    if(num >=0 && num < 10) {
        return '0' + num;
    } else if(num > 9 && num < 16) {
        return (num - 10) + 'a';
    } else {
        return '\0';
    }
}

void dump(void *ptr) {
    // assume 8 bytes
    for(int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
        char* byte = (char *) (ptr + i);
        char high_nibble = (*byte & 0xf0) >> 4;
        char low_nibble = *byte & 0x0f;
        cout << hex(high_nibble) << hex(low_nibble) << "    ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    int num[2] = {123456, 65536};
    dump(&num);
    memcpy(num, num + 1, 1);
    dump(&num);
}
```

The result is:

[image]

What happened? When we offset the pointer by 1 (2nd parameter of memcpy), it pointed to the next int, but when we specified "1" to be copied, it copied 1 byte rather than 1 int. We must specify sizeof(int) as our number of bytes to copy:

```
    memcpy(num, num + 1, sizeof(int));
```

Now we get what we need:

[image]

memcpy does not allow src and dest to overlap.

strncpy is like memcpy but for strings, and if a null character ('\0') is encountered before the number of specified bytes is encountered, the copy ends.